# How can I check compatibility between AWUS amplifiers and antennas?

Tags: wireless-networking, security, hardware-rec

#### What I would like to do

I want to build a powerful combo for pentests using wifi adapter, amplifier and antenna. I don't have bought those components yet because I have a few questions concerning usage and compatibility:

- How can I make sure that these components are compatible before I buy them?
- Do I need to buy 1 APA-M25 per AWUS1900 output or only one is OK?
- Same question for amplifier: Do I need 1 amplifier per antenna output or is one enough?

Below is the targeted hardware details:

#### Targeted hardware

- Wifi adapter [Alfa AWUS1900](https://www.alfa.com.tw/products_detail/2.htm) (dual 2.4GHz + 5GHz)
- Antenna [Alfa APA-M25](https://www.alfa.com.tw/products_detail/234.htm) (dual 2.4GHz + 5GHz)
- Amplifier [Alfa APA05](https://www.alfa.com.tw/products_detail/60.htm) (2.4GHz)
- Amplifier [Alfa APA05-5GHz](https://www.alfa.com.tw/products_detail/58.htm) (5GHz)

Comment: I don't know about the history of your post, but hardware shopping recommendation questions are definitely off topic here, particularly when they are asking about specific components and compatibility. I think if the question were more general ("how can I check compatibility between X and Y?") it would be acceptable. Apologies if you were sent here by mistake. I don't see your question on hardwarerecs.SE.

Comment: Here is the one that was moved from security to hardarerecs : https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/12377/combo-wifi-alfa-awus1900-apa-m25-apa05-apa05-5ghz and this is the one I asked "from scratch" in hardarerecs : https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/12393/combo-wifi-alfa-awus1900-apa-m25-apa05-apa05-5ghz
Btw, I will edit title to match with your recommendation.

Comment: Both of these links are 404 for me; the questions are deleted. Just editing the title will likely not suffice, as you're still asking a very specific question about two pieces of hardware. Ideally we'd like questions to be relevant for future visitors, not just you. Asking the vendor may also be an option. Anyway, this is just my opinion; I'll help put the question into better shape.

Comment: Thenk you for your efforts ! Hope this will avoid a move-then-rejected or a off-topic close